# How can I convert RGB to HSV?

Tags: android, text, colors, textview, hsv

I want to convert RGB pixel colors to HSV. I successfully retrived the red, green, and blue colors of a bitmap. How can I convert this 3 value for an HSV value?

Detail of my code (which retrive the RGB color):

```
 public View.OnTouchListener ivOnTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView) iv).getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgDrawable).getBitmap();

        int coord_x = 0;
        int coord_y = 0;

        while (coord_x <= 1) {
            while (coord_y <= 1) {
                int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(coord_x, coord_y);
                int colorRed = Color.red(touchedRGB);
                int colorGreen = Color.green(touchedRGB);
                int colorBlue = Color.blue(touchedRGB);
                float[] hsv = new float[3];
                /*IT'S WORK, I GET THE RGB COLORS -> colorRGB.append(" || " + "In x: " + coord_x + "and y: " + coord_y + " --> RED: " + colorRed + " GREEN: " + colorGreen + " BLUE: " + colorBlue + " || ");
                coord_y++;*/
                Color.RGBToHSV(colorRed, colorGreen, colorBlue, hsv);
                    colorRGB.setText("THE NEW COLOR");
                    colorRGB.setTextColor(hsv);
            }
            coord_y = 0;
            coord_x++;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

I tried to set the current textView's text to hsv, but my program has crashed. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `hsv` is a float array and the method `setTextColor()` expects an int as parameter.

Once you have your HSV array you can convert it to an int color using this:

```
Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
```

that method will return the int value of your color.

However if all you want is convert those RGB values to a color you can skip the HSV step and use

```
Color.rgb(colorRed, colorGreen, colorBlue);
```

And that will return the int value of the color